# Console.WriteLine not working?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I've created a program which should calculate the surface area of an irregular shaped object, such as a lake.
I read in a file, which contained the values for the x and y values, and the depth.

I'm new to C#, and so I don't fully understand everything yet, but I think my code should work, however, it doesn't seem to be writing the value for the area onto the screen.

I know that `Console.WriteLine(_surface);` SHOULD work , but it I can't seem to get it to do anything, and it's probably in the wrong place!

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

My code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{


    public class ValueXyz
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }


    }


    public class SurfaceCalculator
    {

        private ValueXyz[] _valuesXyz;
        private double _surface;
        private readonly string _textWithValues;
       public SurfaceCalculator(string textWithValues)

        {
            _textWithValues = textWithValues;
            SetValuesToCalculate();
        }

        public double Surface
        {
            get { return _surface; }

        }


        public void CalculateSurface()
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < _valuesXyz.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_valuesXyz[i].Z == 0)
                    _surface = (_valuesXyz[i].X * _valuesXyz[i + 1].Y) - (_valuesXyz[i + 1].X * _valuesXyz[i].Y);

                Console.WriteLine(_surface);
            }


        }


        private void SetValuesToCalculate()
        {
            var valuesXyz = _textWithValues.Split(' ');


            _valuesXyz = valuesXyz.Select(item => new ValueXyz
            {
                X = Convert.ToDouble(item.Split(',')[0]),
                Y = Convert.ToDouble(item.Split(',')[1]),
                Z = Convert.ToInt32(item.Split(',')[2])


            }).ToArray();




        }



        public void TestSurfaceCalculatorGetsAValue()
        {

            var textWithValues = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Lake_Take_Toooooo\Lake_Take_Toooooo\bin\Debug\Lake_Test.csv");
            var calculator = new SurfaceCalculator(_textWithValues);
            calculator.CalculateSurface();


            Assert.IsNotNull(calculator.Surface);

        }

        static void Main()
        {

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time using classes, so apologies if there's an obvious answer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your Main method, you never call any of your other methods.

Comment: This, and a million other beginner errors, can be solved by debugging.  Incredibly important and useful skill.  Just press F10 from Visual Studio and you'll be able to step through each line of code as it executes

Comment: Note that your formula is odd (I'd even pretend it is wrong) and will certainly fail with an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Kieren, while I agree that knowing to use a debugger is an important skill, one should try to debug as little as possible. Even (or especially) beginners should be told how to make unit tests for such tasks. Every minute you spent in a debugger is non-productive time.

Comment: ..and if their unit test fails?  Create ever-more finely-grained unit tests until there's a single IL instruction in each one?  There's a time and a place for unit tests, and this ain't it.  ESPECIALLY for a beginner, single-step debugging, watching variables change, and call stacks, is absolutely invaluable about learning how things come together.  Way more so than unit tests IMO.  [To expand on that in a practical sense, iteratively modifying unit tests, rebuilding a solution and reading unit test output is an awful way of solving many problems.  Just Press F10 and see what's happening.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually call the method inside the `Main` method, which is the program entry point. Like:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        CalculateSurface();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When you run your program, only the code inside the `Main` method is actually executed. If you do not call anything from there then no code is executed.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error Error "The name 'CalculateSurface' does not exist in the current context". How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

No function is being called in the Main event...
I should imagine read key will wait for key input then close, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run this as console application or as unit test? (It looks like you're trying to run it as unit test since you're using NUnit.Framework and there is a Test-method with an Assert...)

If you want to run it as console application, you have to call the code that should get executed in the Main method.

If you want to run it as unit test, you have to add some "attributes" to your test class and test method. The class should have the [TestFixture] attribute, and the method should have the [Test] attribute, like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SurfaceCalculator {

...

[Test]
public void TestSurfaceCalculatorGetsAValue() {
...
}

}
```

Comment: No, I want to run it as a Console application. Should I get rid off the "Assert.IsNotNull(calculator.Surface);" and NUnit.Framework, in that case?

Comment: No, what the other questions and comments say is accurate.  Your `Main` method, the one that is actually the central core of the program, does nothing more than read a key and finish.